# using .each and .after to append data in table jquery

Tags: jquery

```js
$.each(val, function(ind, va) {
  console.log(ind)
  console.log(va)
  if (value.deductiontype == "1") {
    var row = $('<div class="row" style="margin-top:6px;"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="col-md-2"><label class=" col-form-label">' + ind + '</label></div><div class="col-md-10"><input class="form-control payments" type="text" id="" placeholder="' + ind + '" value="' + va + '"/><div></div></div>');

    $("#deduction_end_date").closest(".row").after(row);
  } else if (value.deductiontype == "2") {
    var row = $('<div class="row" style="margin-top:6px;"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-2"><label class=" col-form-label">' + ind + '</label></div><div class="col-md-10"><input class="form-control payments" type="text" id="" placeholder="' + ind + '" value="' + va + '"/></div></div></div></div>');
    $("#deduction_end_date").closest(".row").after(row);
  } else {

  }

});
```

I have above code. what it does is it appends data on a table by iterating over the passed data. It is working ok except that the data in the table are from **last to first**.

I want to append the data from **first to last**

How can I use `.after()` in a way that it will append from **first to last**

Comment: [`.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array i.e. `val.reverse()`

Comment: how can i use this reverse()?

Comment: @Satpal got it can you add it as answer so we can close this OP?

Comment: @Martin `$.each(val.reverse(), function(ind, va) { ...`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan got it i want to give saptal the credit hope you understand this is the first time i heard the reverse :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to append the data from first to last*, You can simply use [`.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array.

> The `reverse()` method reverses an array in place. The first array element becomes the last, and the last array element becomes the first.

```js
$.each(val.reverse(), function(ind, va) {

});
```

Comment: give me 3 minutes to tick the check :)